# Fetch data from another external website using jquery/javascript with html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm completely new to jQuery and PHP.
However with some research i got this code, i just couldn't make it work.

What i did was using this in my php code:

```
<div id="m"></div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="c"></div>
```

And using this in my javascript:

```
 $('#m').load('https://theunderminejournal.com/#eu/outland/search/cyno #search-page');
```

It just didn't show anything what am i doing wrong??

What i want to do is make jquery grab the data form this page: https://theunderminejournal.com/#eu/outland/search/cyno and find the div id "search-page", (which is the table that appears after the search) and copy all the data from that page in the div "search-page" and post it to mine mine page under the div id "m".

Because im very new i would really appreciate if you could show me the code where you included the jquery and all other requirement so i wont make that mistake, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there an error in the JavaScript Console?

Comment: You can only get json from other domains from client side javascript

Comment: The site from where you want to get data, is there a valid API for that website?

Comment: Hmm, as i said im new to javascript so i don't know if the website(undermine journal) im grabbing data from isn't working for fetching data, but is there a workaround this then? Would love some help ;)

Comment: lol if you wanna c the data download CORS extension from chrome

Comment: as i said im completely new, so please tell me how i would do that